# Auth0 API + Spring: How to verify user identity from successful Auth0 API response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt, auth0

## Problem

I'm trying to create an app that uses **Auth0 SPA + React** on the frontend to auth users without ever having to deal with passwords. Then, I'd like to secure any endpoints I create using an **Auth** server that I'm required to create using the **Spring Framework**.

Just to clarify, the flow would be

```
Frontend ->
Auth through Auth0 ->
Redirect to users dashboard on frontend ->
Make HTTP request to endpoint sending JWT returned from Auth0 ->
Endpoint makes request to my Auth Server sending JWT returned from Auth0 ->
Auth server either either returns 401 or user object based on JWT ->
Endpoint grabs data specific to that user from DB ->
Returns data to frontend
```

I've managed to get my frontend to work just fine using the **Quickstart Guide** that **Auth0** provides but I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to get my **Auth Service** to verify the user.

I believe I've come to the conclusion that I need to create an "**API**" on **Auth0** and grab an **access token** and use that to validate the JWT, which in this case is just the **access token** and not the JWT that my frontend contains. I've also got this part working but there doesn't seem to be a way to know who the user is. When testing this "**API**", after sending a valid request I am returned

```
{
  "iss": "https://${username}.auth0.com/",
  "sub": "${alphanumericCharacters}@clients",
  "aud": "${ApiIdentifier}",
  "iat": ${issuedAt},
  "exp": ${expiresAt},
  "azp": "${alphanumericCharacters}",
  "gty": "client-credentials"
}
```

While it's good to know I'm on the right track I can't seem to figure out what to do with this response to find the user.

## Expected

I expect to be able to identify a specific user after validating an **access_token** from my **Auth Service**

## Code

I don't have much code to show but I'll provide what I can from my **Auth Service**

### SecurityConfiguration.java

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${auth0.audience}")
    private String audience;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuer;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/api/validate")
                    .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                    .jwt();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        NimbusJwtDecoderJwkSupport jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoderJwkSupport)
                JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer);

        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new AudienceValidator(audience);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);

        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);

        return jwtDecoder;
    }

}
```

### AudienceValidator.java

```java
public class AudienceValidator implements OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> {
    private final String audience;

    public AudienceValidator(String audience) {
        this.audience = audience;
    }

    public OAuth2TokenValidatorResult validate(Jwt jwt) {
        OAuth2Error error = new OAuth2Error("invalid_token", "The required audience is missing", null);

        if (jwt.getAudience().contains(audience)) {
            return OAuth2TokenValidatorResult.success();
        }
        return OAuth2TokenValidatorResult.failure(error);
    }
}
```

### ValidateController.java

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/validate")
public class ValidateController {

    @GetMapping
    public boolean validate() {
        return true;  // only returns if successfully authed
    }

}
```

Comment: By using  oauth2ResourceServer(), you are validating the token with Auth0. Is this extra validation to verify the token belongs to a specific user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading through the docs I've found my solution.

It turns out that I don't need to create an "**API**" on **Auth0** but instead need to use my **Applications** endspoint(s) from **Auth0**. **Auth0** provides many endpoints based on your account that you can take advantage of from any of your applications (CLI, Server, Client, etc.) as long as you can:

- Make an HTTP Request
- Provide credentials

So the way to get a users information is [explained here](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#get-user-info).

## Data flow

Using my projects auth/data flow it's pretty much:

- Using [@auth0/auth0-spa-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/auth0-spa-js) on the frontend, you can grab a users **access token** after a successful auth by using the [getTokenSilently() method](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-spa-js#call-an-api).
- Send up HTTP request to your **Rest Service**
- **Rest Service** sends that token to your **Auth Service**
- **Auth Service** sends **GET** request to `https://myAuth0Username.auth0.com/userinfo` with the `Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}` header. [Example](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#get-user-info)
- If successfully authed from **Auth0**

  - Returns your users information such as "name", "email", etc.
- Else

  - Returns a 403 Forbidden HTTP Status
- **Auth Service** then returns **user object** to **Rest Service**
- **Rest Service** then does necessary logic for that endpoint (DB query, another HTTP request, etc.)

### Example Auth Service endpoint to validate tokens and return a user

**ValidateController.java**

```java
package x.SpringTodo_Auth.Controllers;

import x.SpringTodo_Auth.Models.User;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/validate")
public class ValidateController {

    @GetMapping
    public Object validate() {
        // Create and set the "Authorization" header before sending HTTP request
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("headers", headers);

        // Use the "RestTemplate" API provided by Spring to make the HTTP request
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Object user = restTemplate.exchange("https://myAuth0Username.auth0.com/userinfo", HttpMethod.POST, entity, User.class);
        return user;
    }

}
```

**User.java** (This is the class passed to the `restTemplate.exchange(...)` method as the last argument

```java
package x.SpringTodo_Auth.Models;

public class User {

    private String sub;
    private String given_name;
    private String family_name;
    private String nickname;
    private String name;
    private String picture;
    private String locale;
    private String updated_at;
    private String email;
    private boolean email_verified;

    // Getters/setters (or you can use Lombok)
}
```

Comment: Would you want to do a callout to Auth0 for every single request coming in from your SPA? (If so, you can consider using filters in your security config to pre-check all requests).